# A little arrow appear on my dropdown menu

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap

No need to explain just look at

http://blog.appyourself.com

try to navigate on the header menu and when you fly over the connexion bouton a little white arrow appear i dont know why

See here:

[image]

Edit : Here is the code

```
     <header class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top bs-docs-nav" role="banner">
         <div class="container">
         <div class="navbar-header">
         <button class="navbar-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".bs-navbar-collapse">
         <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
         <span class="icon-bar"></span>
         <span class="icon-bar"></span>
         <span class="icon-bar"></span>
         </button>
         <a href="http://www.appyourself.com/" class="navbar-brand">
         <img src="http://www.appyourself.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/LOGO-APPYOURSELF.png"></a>
         </div>
         <nav class="collapse navbar-collapse bs-navbar-collapse" role="navigation">
         <div class="menu-menu-principal-container"><ul id="menu-menu-principal" class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right"><li id="menu-item-242" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children dropdown"><a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Suite marketing</a>
         <ul class="dropdown-menu">
         <li id="menu-item-243" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page"><a href="http://www.appyourself.com/produit/cms/">Sites  &#038;  applications</a></li> <li id="menu-item-244" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page"><a href="http://www.appyourself.com/produit/crm/">CRM</a></li><!--.dropdown-->
         </ul>
         </li><li id="menu-item-276" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children dropdown"><a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Secteurs</a>
         <ul class="dropdown-menu">
         <li id="menu-item-275" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page"><a href="http://www.appyourself.com/tpe-pme/hotel/">Hôtel</a></li> <li id="menu-item-388" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page"><a href="http://www.appyourself.com/tpe-pme/camping/">Camping</a></li>  <li id="menu-item-462" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page"><a href="http://www.appyourself.com/tpe-pme/bed-breakfast/">Bed  &#038;  Breakfast</a></li> <li id="menu-item-739" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page"><a href="http://www.appyourself.com/tpe-pme/restaurant-bar/">Restaurant &#038; Bar</a></li> <li id="menu-item-692" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page"><a href="http://www.appyourself.com/tpe-pme/spa/">Beauty &#038; Spa</a></li>    <li id="menu-item-648" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page"><a href="http://www.appyourself.com/tpe-pme/commerces-services/">Commerces  &#038;  Services</a></li>   <li id="menu-item-649" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page"><a href="http://www.appyourself.com/tpe-pme/agence-immobiliere/">Agence  Immobilière</a></li>   <li id="menu-item-650" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page"><a href="http://www.appyourself.com/tpe-pme/auto-moto/">Auto-Moto</a></li>  <li id="menu-item-647" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page"><a href="http://www.appyourself.com/tpe-pme/agence-de-voyage/">Agence  de  voyage</a></li><!--.dropdown-->
         </ul>
         </li><li id="menu-item-1301" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page"><a href="http://www.appyourself.com/partenaires/">Partenaires</a></li><li id="menu-item-360" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page"><a href="http://www.appyourself.com/qui-sommes-nous/">AppYourself</a></li><li id="menu-item-656" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children dropdown"><a href="http://pro.appyourself.com/users/login" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Connexion</a>
         <ul class="dropdown-menu">
         <li id="menu-item-936" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom"><a href="http://pro.appyourself.com/users/login?btag=hotel">Hôtel</a></li>  <li id="menu-item-937" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom"><a href="http://pro.appyourself.com/users/login?btag=camping">Camping</a></li>   <li id="menu-item-938" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom"><a href="http://pro.appyourself.com/users/login?btag=bb">Bed  &#038;  Breakfast</a></li> <li id="menu-item-939" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom"><a href="http://pro.appyourself.com/users/login?btag=restaurant">Restaurant &#038; Bar</a></li>  <li id="menu-item-940" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom"><a>Beauty &#038; Spa</a></li><!--.dropdown-->
         </ul>
         </li>
         </ul>
         </div>

         </nav>

         </div>
</header>
```

Comment: Yes need to explain an add the code here. If links get down then the question is just spam on SO.

Comment: See the ":before" pseudo element, here ([w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_pseudo_elements.asp))

Comment: i hope you noticed the other problems with your page, e.g: in chrome, you menu is a bit lower then the top bar, on mobile, you have twice the small menu bar.

Comment: I am working on that kind of problem yeah thank to points out

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's on the Devil's line of bootstrap (line 666):

```
.navbar .nav>li>.dropdown-menu:before {
    content: '';
    display: inline-block;
    border-left: 7px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    border-right: 7px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    border-bottom: 7px solid #CCC;
    border-bottom-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    position: absolute;
    top: -7px;
    left: 9px;
}
```

Remove it, or overwrite it in your custom CSS.

As Danko points out, there's also an `:after` that may be causing this. It's on the line after (667):

```
.navbar .nav>li>.dropdown-menu:after {
    content: '';
    display: inline-block;
    border-left: 6px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    border-right: 6px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    border-bottom: 6px solid #FFF;
    position: absolute;
    top: -6px;
    left: 10px;
}
```